# Can't perform attribute binding on an element that has a bootrap class assigned to it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am developing an Angular 2 web app and I use bootstrap for styling. I have a little triangle that sometimes must be visible, sometimes invisible. It is represented by the following item:

```
<span [attr.visibility]="myspanvisibylity" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>
```

the variable myspanvisibility belongs to the component and sometimes evaluates to 'visible', other times to 'hidden'. the problem is that it's always visible. Maybe because the bootstrap class overrides it?

Comment: Have you tried to to add `<div>{{myspanvisibility}}</div>` somewhere in the template to verify that the right value is bound?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `visibility` is a span attribute. You can use the html5 attribute `[hidden]="myspanvisibility === 'hidden'"` or the bootstrap css class `[class.invisible]="myspanvisibility === 'hidden'"` or the css attribute `[style.visiblity]="myspanvisibility"`.